# What, specifically is the "Facebook ID"?

Tags: hyperlink, facebook-like

I am trying to add a "like" button link to my website. I enter all of the required info on the facebook developers page to generate the html, but it won't accept anything I have tried as a "facebook ID". I have tried the registered name, the e-mail address, etc. but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

registered id is the id linked to your Facebook. You can find it by going to a picture of your's and check the id at the url.

Answer (score 0):

To quickly find your facebook id, go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer in a browser that you've logged into Facebook with and it should tell your id.